# Can I shoot a multiple exposure with more than 2 exposures without manual intervention?

Tags: nikon, film, multiple-exposure

I’m considering the Nikon F75 for a film project requiring multiple exposures per frame.

Does the Nikon F75 have a mode where the frame does not advance, for an arbitrary number of multiple exposures on the same frame?

From the [manual (page 70, takes a while to load)](https://cdn-10.nikon-cdn.com/pdf/manuals/archive/N75-N75QD.pdf#page=70), it is clear that creating multiple exposures with more than 2 frame is possible:

> To take more than two shots on the same frame, rotate the Command Dial while pressing the [bkt] button again after the first shot is taken ...

But it’s not clear to me if it is always necessary to “prep” each additional exposure on the same frame with a manually pressing the [bkt] button as described.

I would like to use the same frame for (more than 2) multiple exposures, unattended, with a remote trigger.

Can the F75 be set in a mode, where the frame does not advance at all between exposures?

Answer (score 4):

From the same manual that you linked to, and the last sentence in the same paragraph that you mentioned:

> To take more than two shots on the same frame, rotate the Command Dial
> while pressing the [bkt] button again after the first shot is taken by
> depressing the shutter release button and while [multiple exposure indicator] is blinking so [multiple exposure indicator]
> appears without blinking. **Repeat this operation as many times as you
> wish to continue taking pictures on the same frame.**

That would indicate that you *do* have to manually prep the camera each time you want to take a multiple exposure. (Which would be a reasonable thing for a consumer camera, as you want to minimize the possibility of people taking multiple exposures by accident.)

Comment: I guess the OP was wondering if there is a way around that prep.

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke And the answer would seem to be "no"